# Angular 7 Universal : Unable to load simple Http request to Express server (SSR)

Tags: angular, http, express, nginx, angular-universal

My application is for now a simple try before go ahead : I'm hopping to deploy an **angular 7 front-end**, working with an **Express node server in SSR** (SEO optimization and access to WooCommerceAPI). A **Nginx server** comes here to link the Wordpress backend part, and ensure **proxy** to my universal app.

On local, my simple tests in SSR work well. My angular app address http request to my express server, this one use woocommerceAPI to fetch some products and i get back Json in return. (**windows 10, XAMPP**).

On my VPS (**debian 9, Nginx**), for some reason, my angular app **can't reach** the Express server. I get a CONNECTION_REFUSED error (message : "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"). The log doesn't provide more leads. I tried many things without results. I enabled CORS in both nginx and Express. I'm on this for several days, any idea could help me a lot !

My angular SSR is running on port 9000. Here are some codes parts :

---

## Edit > SOLVED !

Ok, two things needs to be changed here. **First**, in the angular app call to express : 
change http://localhost:9000/api/req by http://your-public-ip-address:9000/api/req.

**Second** : since my wordpress folder (and url to access) is in a subdirectory, the nginx location needs to be configurated with these lines :

```
location /wp {
        root /var/www;
        index index.php;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        ...
        try_files $uri $uri/ /wp/index.php$is_args$args;
        ...
        location ~ \.php$ {
           ... everything is okay here ...
               just be sure to configure your fpm port
        }
}
```

---

---

**Angular > express Call**

```
constructor( private http: HttpClient ) { }

getAllProducts() {
  // THIS LINE NEEDS TO BE CHANGED !!!
  let response = this.http.get('http://localhost:9000/api/req')
      .subscribe(
          data => console.log('SUCCESS ', data),
          error => console.log('OOPS ', error)
  );
}
```

**Express > woocommerce Call**

```
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());

app.get('/api/req', (req, res) => {
  console.log("SERVER : Begin to get all Posts");
  WooCommerce.getAsync('products').then(function(result) {
    res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
  });
});

// Serving on 9000
app.listen(PORT,() => {
  console.log(`serving the site for you at http://localhost:${PORT}!`);
});
```

**Nginx config file**

```
server {
        server_name xxxxxx;
        listen 80;

     #Proxy to angular App Universal
     location / {
        include cors; #call to conf file - enabling CORS
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connecion 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    #Link to wordpress / woocommerce admin interface

    #CERTAINS LINES NEED TO BE CHANGED / ADDED !!!

    location /wp {
        include cors;
        root /var/www/;
        index index.php;
        allow 127.0.0.1;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/blog.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/blog.error.log;

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost' always;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:7000;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading me !

Comment: Are you set up nginx in your local machine or any server machine?

Comment: You should use your server domain address or public IP address instead of this.http.get('http://localhost:9000/api/req')

Comment: Hmm you are right Richardon, it's better with my public ip address ! I now get a 404 statusCode, i will investigate tomorrow. That's a step forward, thank you ! Nginx is only set up on the prod distant server, it's the first time I use it